# Is it possible to set the width of a roundrect to its content width?

Tags: vml

I am building a button, using vml because it's the only way to make it rounded on Outlook emails. I need its width to depend on its content. However I can't find a way to do so. The only width I am able to give it is a fixed width.

```
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
     style="width:200px; height:41px; v-text-anchor:middle;"
     arcsize="10%"
     stroke="f"
     fillcolor="#d62828">
  <w:anchorlock/>
  <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
    Découvrir
  </center>
</v:roundrect>
```

Is it possible to make its width depend on its content width? And if not, is it possible to make it equal to 100% of its parent (I tried mso-width-percent but it depends on the viewport width, not the parent width)?

Comment: There is a ms css property which might help: `style="mso-fit-shape-to-text: true;"`, but I don't know if it works horizontally too.

Comment: @biziclop thx, I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but in case someone is still trying to figure this out, I was able to get the `<v:roundrect>` to expand to the size of the text with the following:

```
style="mso-wrap-style:none; mso-fit-shape-to-text: true;"
```

The problem was that it was wrapping on words causing it to look like it wasn't expanding correctly.  This resolves that.